# Node Functions Return Nothing sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to use sqlite3 in a project and I'm running into a problem. My functions aren't returning any values. I added a `console.log` before the return statement and oddly enough, it works, but logs *after* the function has returned.

```
console.log(getNext());

function establishConnection(callback) {
    const db = new sqlite3.Database('database.db');
    db.serialize(() => {
        callback(db);
    });
    db.close();
}

function getNext() {
    establishConnection(db => {
        db.get('SELECT col1, col2 FROM table ORDER BY priority LIMIT 1;', (err, row) => {
            console.log([row.col1, row.col2]); // works
            return [row.col1, row.col2];       // doesn't work
        });
    });
}
```

I'm no expert at Node but this seems like something that should work and I don't understand why it doesn't. Could someone please explain this to me and possibly provide a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getNext` is asynchronous, this is why you see logging after the function "returns". Your code currently uses callback style so this answer will follow your format. Using [promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) or [async/await](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions) is a more modern approach.

```
getNext(result => console.log(result));

function establishConnection(callback) {
    const db = new sqlite3.Database('database.db');
    db.serialize(() => {
        callback(db);
    });
    db.close();
}

function getNext(callback) {
    establishConnection(db => {
        db.get('SELECT col1, col2 FROM table ORDER BY priority LIMIT 1;', (err, row) => {
            callback([row.col1, row.col2]);
        });
    });
}
```